# Trying to add the email subject, body, and name to an excel sheet from a c# application

Tags: c#, excel, email, transfer

As the title stated, I want to transfer data from an email to an excel sheet. But when I run the program it doesn't run with the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel namespace included. I have downloaded the necessary NuGets, and the code looks right to me. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

excel.Visible = true;

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Users\\Ty\\Documents\\Returns.xlsx");

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet sheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets[1];

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application outlook = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();

NameSpace ns = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI");

MAPIFolder folder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);

MailItem email = folder.Items[1] as MailItem;

//Use a regular expression to extract the name from the email body
string pattern = @"Full Name:\s*(.*)";

Match match = Regex.Match(email.Body, pattern);

string name = "";

if (match.Success)
{
    name = match.Groups[1].Value;
}

//Add the email subject, body, and name to the Excel sheet
int row = sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1; // Find the last used row

sheet.Cells[row, 1] = email.Subject;
sheet.Cells[row, 2] = email.Body;
sheet.Cells[row, 3] = name;
```

Comment: This is not the entire code by the way, if needed I can post more but I believe the error is in here

Comment: What error messages do you get? Or if there are no error messages what doesn't work?

Comment: @NineBerry When I run the program with this code in it and i do the upload it just doesn't work. I have put a try catch around it and it just bypasses it. I have no clue as to why it isn't working. It's a web program

Comment: What kind of web application is it? ASP.net? Running on IIS or some other server?

Comment: @NineBerry Yes, asp.net, and running on an IIS

Comment: Office Automation doesn't support this scenario. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2

Comment: @NineBerry darn

Comment: If your organization uses Office connected to Office 365, you can use the Microsoft Graph to interface with mails and workbooks. etc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/overview

Comment: @NineBerry Thanks, will definitely look into that!